# Does freezing keras layers reduce memory needed for training?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, tf.keras

I have pretrained weights of a large model that can't fit in my vram. If I freeze layers, the memory needed for training will be reduced? If so, the freezed layer weights aren't saved in vram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **frozen weights** are parts of your model's **parameters**. So if you freeze them, the only thing will happen, that no calculation will be doing with them (note: this is tend to be true, but not always true), therefore the optimization will be **faster**.
As they are still part of the whole optimizing process, **they will be loaded** in the GPU memory during the optimization(training) like they weren't frozen.